# lxpanel configuration

Tags: lxde, lxpanel

Somewhere between lxpanel 0.6.1 and lxpanel 0.9.? the look of icons for running programs on the panel changed.

The old way, you just get an icon

[image]

The new way, you get icon + info

[image]

Is there a configuration setting to get back to the old behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As so often happens, I found the answer after posting a question.

Right-click the panel, select "Panel Settings", click the "Panel Applets" tab, click "Task Bar (Windows List)", click "Edit", and tick the box that says "Icons Only".